# connect() не подключается

Tags: c++, linux, c, сокет, unix

Пишу клиент-серверную модель в рамках UNIX и возникла проблема с тем, что вызов connect() к клиенте стабильно завершается неудачей.

**Сервер:**

```
#define ADDRESS "mysocket" // адрес для связи

int main ()
{
char c;
int i, d, d1, len, ca_len;
FILE * fp;
struct sockaddr_un sa, ca;

if((d = socket (AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror ("client: socket");
    exit(1);
}
sa.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy (sa.sun_path, ADDRESS);
unlink (ADDRESS);
len = sizeof ( sa.sun_family) + strlen (sa.sun_path);
if ( bind ( d, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa)) < 0 ) {
    perror ("server: bind");
    exit (1);
}

if ( listen ( d, 5) < 0 ) {
    perror ("server: listen");
    exit (1);
}

ca_len = sizeof ca;
if (( d1 = accept(d, (struct sockaddr*)&ca, (socklen_t*)&ca_len)) < 0 ) {
    perror ("server: accept");
    exit (1);
}

fp = fdopen (d1, "r");
c = fgetc (fp);
send (d1, "server", 7, 0);
putchar ( c );
close (d1);
exit (0);
```

}

**Основные моменты клиентской части:**

```
#define ADDRESS "mysocket" // адрес для связи

int main ()
{
    char c;
    int i, s, len;
    FILE *fp;
    struct sockaddr_un sa;

    if ((s = socket (AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
        perror ("client: socket");
        exit (1);
    }

    sa.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy (sa.sun_path, ADDRESS);

    len = sizeof ( sa.sun_family) + strlen ( sa.sun_path);
    if ( connect ( s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa)) < 0 ){
        perror ("client: connect");
        exit (1);
    }
/*--------------------------------------------- */
// читаем сообщения сервера, пишем серверу:
    fp = fdopen (s, "r");
    c = fgetc (fp);
/* ............................ */
    send (s, "client", 7, 0);
    close (s);
    exit (0);
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём моя ошибка и почему так происходит?
Пробовал перезагружать систему (на случай, если у ОС забились сокеты и проч) - не помогает.

Comment: Приводите [mcve], а не "основные моменты"

Comment: Привёл в отредактированной версии вопроса

Comment: Третий аргумент `bind` должен быть размером структуры, на которую указывает второй. Для `connect`  то же самое

Comment: Исправил, однако проблему, увы, не решило

Comment: По-моему в вопросе ничего не изменилось. И ошибки, которая печатается, тоже нет. *"простоты отладки имя сервера DefaultServer1"* - в коде этого нету

Comment: Дополнил и поправил

Comment: Ну вы пишите "исправил", однако в коде в вопросе длина как передавалась неправильная, так и передается. *"Ошибки тут никакой и не печатается"* - а вызов `perror` должен печатать. Также нет заголовочных файлов, откуда там берутся все используемые идентификаторы?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду, говоря, что длинна передаётся неправильно? Я сделал в точности, как вы и сказали, написав в качестве третьего аргумента sizeof от второго. Заголовочные файлы намеренно не стал указывать, поскольку предполагаю, что человек, способный решить проблему, не будет озадачен этим вопросом при попытке скомпилировать код, а захламлять вопрос не хочу. perror же печатает ровно то, что я туда написал в случае возврата -1 из connect(), никакой другой конструктивной информации система не предоставляет (поэтому я и говорю, что сообщений нет)

Comment: Да, действительно, теперь вопрос обновился. Хотя непонятно, почему там высчитывание `len` осталось.  `Заголовочные файлы намеренно не стал указывать, поскольку предполагаю, что человек, способный решить проблему, не будет озадачен этим вопросом при попытке скомпилировать код,` - это противоречит тому, что изложено в ссылке про минимальный воспроизводимый пример. В вопросе должен быть приведет настоящий код, который вызывает проблему. А заодно следовало бы привести информацию о системе, компиляторе, команды компилятора, лог сборки и лог работы.

Comment: Тут же в вопросе обсуждается не проблема с кодом, который есть у вас, в проблема с кодом, который предоставлен в вопросе. А текущем виде он даже не собирается. `perror же печатает ровно то, что я туда написал в случае возврата` - нет, `perror` еще печатает сообщение об ошибке по значeнию `errno`. Ну или вы используйте какой-то собственный `perror`, однако читающие вопрос об этом не могут узнать, так как не приведены соотв. объявления или инклюды.